# PDF in Asp.Net MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I'm looking for free for comercial use library which provides creating PDF documents. I found this PDFsharp & MigraDoc. If somebody works on it I'll be appreciative for good and bad sides of this library. I want to use it for generating plain text documents and docs with many graphics. Maybe somebody used other similary librarys and can recomend other solution?

Upfront thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iTextSharp is the one you might be looking for. 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the iTextSharp. Below article will help you to kick start,

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/686994/Create-Read-Advance-PDF-Report-using-iTextSharp-in